# HTML 5 canvas and moving objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am having a look at HTML 5 canvas today and I would like to move 3 circles on the canvas. From what I have read so far I need to redraw the circles each time (every 60 miliseconds seems like a good place to start) and clear out the old circle so that the new one with its new position on the screen takes its place

So far I have a `draw()` that will render 3 circles each of a different colour, the idea is to take control of each circle.

I am looking for some guidance here on how to initially set this up and get each ball moving.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ball Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #ball-canvas {
            border: 1px solid #666;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="ball-canvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>

        function renderCircle(context, x, y, radius, fill) {
            var strokeWidth = 2
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius - (2 * strokeWidth), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.fillStyle = fill;
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
            context.strokeStyle = '#666';
            context.stroke();
        }

        function draw() {
        renderCircle(context, radius, canvas.height / 2, radius, 'yellow');
        renderCircle(context, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, radius, 'blue');
        renderCircle(context, canvas.width - radius , canvas.height / 2, radius, 'red');

        }


        var canvas = document.getElementById('ball-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        var radius  = 50;


        setInterval(draw, 1000 / 60);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a brief description of how to move circles on html canvas:**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/JQQP9/

Create an object that defines each circle:

```
var circle1={
    x:50,
    y:50,
    radius:25,
}

var circle2={
    x:100,
    y:100,
    radius:25,
}
```

Add these circle objects to an array:

```
var circles=[];

circles.push(circle1);
circles.push(circle2);
```

Make a function that will draw all circles in the array.

This function clears the canvas and redraws all circles at their currently assigned x,y:

```
function draw(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        var c=circles[i];
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(c.x,c.y,c.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

To "move" the circles you change the x,y properties of a circle and redraw the circles:

```
circles[0].x+=1;
circles[1].y+=1;
draw();
```

To animate the movements, you might consider checking out `requestAnimationFrame` which efficiently creates an animation loop.  IMHO, it is the preferred looping method for all but simple animations.

```
var frameCount=0;

animate();

function animate(){
    if(frameCount<160){requestAnimationFrame(animate);}
    circles[0].x+=1;
    circles[1].y+=1;
    draw();
    frameCount++;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the in depth answer, out of interest how could i add a color to each circle, its fillStyle isnt it? and i could add color to the javascript object, so color: '#3299CC', but fillStyle doesnt accept a string does it? does that make any sense ?

Comment: Your intuition is correct.  You can add a `fill:"#3299CC"` property to all your circle objects (you can vary the color string if desired).  Then you can do `context.fillStyle=c.fill` in the draw function to cause your circles to have the fill defined in their objects.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this would be to use window.requestAnimationFrame. This will essentially let you redraw the canvas every frame that the browser checks if it needs to redraw the screen. Below is my modification of your draw method and initialization code.

```
    function draw() {
      // schedule another draw for the next animation frame by calling 
      // requestAnimationFrame with itself as a callback
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);

      // clear the canvas (otherwise your circles will leave trails)
      canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // calc a new position for the circles based on the current time
      var now = +new Date();
      var halfWidth = canvas.width / 2; // (waste to recheck each frame)
      var maxX = canvas.width - radius; // to avoid drawing the circles off screen
      var spaceBetween = canvas.width / 3;
      var x1 = (halfWidth + now) % maxX;
      var x2 = (x1 + spaceBetween) % maxX;
      var x3 = (x2 + spaceBetween) % maxX;

      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var spaceBetween = canvas.width / 3;
      renderCircle(context, x1, y, radius, 'yellow');
      renderCircle(context, x2, y, radius, 'blue');
      renderCircle(context, x3, y, radius, 'red');
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('ball-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    var radius  = 50;

    // start the animation
    draw();
```