# Add touchmove event to canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touchmove

Helo,

is this possible to add touchmove event to canvas element like: [myGamePiece](http://www.w3schools.com/games/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_component_simple)  (from w3c schools) so I can move it by touching the screen? I tried something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    myGamePiece.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
       ...my code
       e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
}, false)
```

but the console log shows me:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Regards

Comment: Your `myGamePiece` Object is not a page element you can add event-listeners to, it is just information generated from the `component` consturctor that represents the properties of something drawn on the canvas.  In order to move the red square you must log the position of a `canvas` touch-type event, compare it to the position and/or boundary of the red square, track and log the position of any move-type event, and redraw the canvas with a red square whose co-ordinates follow the move-type event. This SO answer may be useful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24958827/4746328

Comment: [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml) - this was helpful